# YouTube subscription list scraping; yt-formatted-string not recognized from the HTML page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I tried to scrape my YouTube subscriptions list into a csv file. But I faced a problem in the middle of the code. Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/feed/channels'
source = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'lxml')


text = soup.find_all('yt-formatted-string', {'id': 'text'})
for i in range(len(text)):
 print(text[i].yt-formatted-string.text)
```

I am wondering why vscode didn't recognize 'yt-formatted-string' while it's found on the HTML page. Also when I tried another div from HTML, this code didn't give any output.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because you haven't logged in to your account while sending requests to *"https://www.youtube.com/feed/channels"*. You must have to login first to get **All subscriptions**.

You can solve this problem by using [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium). First, login to your account using selenium, and then you can use either selenium or beautifulsoup to extract subscriptions from that page.